# Как правильно вызвать функцию при ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

При клике на блок с классом main-block ajaxом добавляются элементы.
Функция, которая отрабатывает при клике на элемент, который добавляется ajax

```
function test() {
    $('.element').click(function () {
       alert('нажал');
    });
}
```

Ajax, и вызов функции

```
$('.main-block').one("click", function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'ajax/action.php',
        data: {ACTION : 'compilePrice'},
        success: function (data) {
            test();
        }
    });
});
```

Проблема в том, что если у меня блоков с классом main-block несколько, и я на нажал на все, то при клике на блок с классом element, который появился после клика на первый блок, у меня вылетает столько alertов, сколько раз я нажал на блок с классом main-block.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать правильно?

Comment: Потому что селектор ` $('.element')` выбирает **все** на странице. Выбирай только те, которые добавляешь.

Comment: @Grundy при чем тут сколько селектор выбирает? Проблема в том, что он при каждом клике навешивает новый хэндлер на класс.

Comment: @Grundy, Нужно в функцию передавать данные, которые добавляются, each'ом пройти все селекторы ` $('.element')`, и на каждый повесить обработчик клика. Так что ли?

Comment: @teran, он навешивает при каждом клике **на все**

Comment: @Максим, причем тут each??? each не нужен. Тебе не нужны все элементы на странице `$('.element')`, вместо этого передавай в функцию `test` **только добавленные**

Comment: @Grundy ну да. это взгляд на проблему с другой стороны :) короче `$(document).on('click', '.element', function(){});`  решит проблему в любом случае

Comment: @teran, вот вообще ни разу. Плюс делегировать с документа - не красиво :-)

Comment: @Grundy с чего это ни разу? Я не предлагаю ведь в аяксе  навешивать, а просто написать один раз обработчик, вообще без привязки к этом аяксу. А с документа конечно не красиво, но за неимением структуры документа по другому объяснить сложно :)

Comment: @teran, спасибо, что-то не подумал что так написать можно

Comment: вместо `document` только используйте ближайшего возможного и подходящего предка для всех этих элементов